# error in updating table in sqlite3 xcode 6

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sqlite

i'm new to iOS.
currently i'm trying to build my own app using xcode6 obj C with sqlite3.

i'm able to open DB, create table, however not able to update. can you please help me on this? code as below

```
    @interface ViewController : UIViewController
    {
        sqlite3 *db;
    }

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self openDB];
    [self createTable:@"custadd" withField1:@"ID" withField2:@"Name" withField3:@"Phone"];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

    //to create table    
    -(void) createTable:(NSString *) tableName
             withField1: (NSString*) field1
             withField2: (NSString*) field2
             withField3: (NSString*) field3
    {
        char *err;
        NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Create table if not exists '%@' ('%@' char primary key, '%@' char, '%@' char not null );",tableName,field1,field2,field3];
        if (sqlite3_exec(db, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err) != SQLITE_OK) {
            sqlite3_close(db);
            NSAssert(0, @"Could not create table");
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Table created");
        }
    }

    - (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender {
    //    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO custadd('ID','Name','Phone') Values ('%@','%@','%@']",custid,name,phone];

    //    NSString *sql = @"INSERT INTO custadd(1,ose,012345)";
        NSString *sql = @".table";

        char *err;
        if (sqlite3_exec(db, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err) != SQLITE_OK ){
    //        sqlite3_close(custadd);
    //        NSAssert(0, @"Could not update table");
            NSLog(@"table not updated");

        } else{
            NSLog(@"table updated");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Comment: If it's failing at `create table` statement, see if `err` is `NULL` and if not, log it. If it's failing on `insert`, log `sqlite3_err_msg`. Finally, you probably should capture what the return value was if not `SQLITE_OK` It's silly to guess what the error is. See what SQLite tells you.

Comment: BTW, it looks like `saveButton` is trying to perform `.table`?!? What is your intent there? That's not valid SQL. When you invoke SQLite programmatically, you can't perform those `.` commands that you use in the command line program.

Comment: Finally, when you do get around to doing proper `insert` SQL, if this data includes anything provided by the end user, you really shouldn't be using `sqlite3_exec` (because it will fail if the user had `'` in their value). Instead, use `sqlite3_prepare_v2`, with `?` for the values (not inserting values with `stringWithFormat`), then bind values with `sqlite3_bind_xxx`. Finally, `sqlite3_step` to perform update and `sqlite3_finalize` to clean up.

Comment: @Rob, i was trying to insert NSString *sql = @"INSERT INTO custadd(1,ose,012345)"; however it didn't work. hence i was trying to see if my table can be populated by issuing .table command. i used sqlite3_exec as per the tutorial on youtube :)

Comment: I'd advise you find another tutorial, then. (lol) `sqlite_exec` is not advisable when inserting string values into a database. It's simpler (which is probably why the tutorial used it), but has serious limitations/problems.

Comment: @Rob, thank you. i'll google see if there's any simple tutorial with sqlite3_prepare_v2. thank you for your great advise. it will be great if you have any recommended links to share! cheers.